# Error en Pandas DataFrames con Python

Tags: python, script

```
import pyautogui
import time
import timeit
import datetime
import cv2
import pytesseract
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageGrab
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp
from datetime import datetime

macd = 0.0

# captura de pantalla cada 5 seg. calcula MACD

# Create an empty DataFrame with columns "Timestamp," "price," and "price"
data = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Timestamp", "price", "macd"])

def macdsignal(macd, data):
# Manual MACD, calcula EMA12, Ema 26 y EMA9
    if len(data) >= 15:
        #pdb.set_trace()
        ShortEMA = data["price"].ewm(span=12, adjust=False).mean()
        #EMA10 = data["precio"].ewm(span=10, adjust=False).mean()
        print("short ema = ", ShortEMA)
        #LongEMA = data["price"].ewm(span=26, adjust=False).mean()
        #print("long ema = ", LongEMA)
        # calculamos el valor de MACD y su Señal
        macd = ShortEMA
        #MACD = ShortEMA - LongEMA
        data.loc[len(data) -1, "macd"] = macd

    else:
        data.loc[:, "macd"] = 0.0

    return(macd, data)

# Especifica las coordenadas de la pantalla que deseas capturar
left = 125
top = 140
right = 230
bottom = 192

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract'

while True:
    # Toma una captura de pantalla de la parte superior izquierda que cubra 1/16 de la pantalla
    #screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(x, y, width // 8, pyautogui.size().height // 4))
    screenshot = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(left, top, right, bottom))
    # Crea un sello de tiempo único para el nombre del archivo
    timestamp = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    print(timestamp)
    # Guarda la captura de pantalla con un nombre único
    #screenshot.save(f'D:\VICTOR\Documentos\CODIGOS\CAPTURAS\screenshot_{timestamp}.png')
    print("captura realizada")
    #screenshot.save(f'D:\VICTOR\Documentos\CODIGOS\CAPTURAS\screenshot_{time.time()}.png')
    #print("screenshot grabada")

    # Convierte la imagen en un objeto de matriz NumPy
    img = np.array(screenshot)
    # Convierte la imagen a escala de grises
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Aplica un filtro de umbral para mejorar la calidad de la imagen
    thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    cv2.imwrite(r'D:\VICTOR\Documentos\CODIGOS\CAPTURAS\thresh_{time.time()}.png', thresh)

     # Usa pytesseract para extraer el texto de la imagen
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh, lang='spa')
    
    #cv2.waitKey(0)
    #cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    # Convierte el texto a un número flotante
    try:
        number = float(text)
        print(f'El número extraído de la imagen es: {number}')
        
    except ValueError:
        print('No se pudo extraer un número de la imagen.')

    if len(data) == 0:
        try:
            price = number
            #data.loc[len(data)] = [timestamp, price]
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input. Please enter a valid price with a decimal point.")
            #continue

    else:
        try:
            new_price = number

            # Get the previous price from the DataFrame
            previous_price = data["price"].iloc[-1]
            print("len(data) previous = ", len(data), previous_price)

            # Calculate the percentage difference
            percent_difference = abs(new_price - previous_price)*100 / previous_price
            print("percent difference = ", percent_difference)
            if percent_difference <= 4.0:
                price = new_price
                print(price)
                #data.loc[len(data)] = [timestamp, new_price]
            else:
                price = previous_price
                print("Invalid input. The price differs by more than 4% from the previous entry. Please enter a valid price.")

        except ValueError:
                            print("Invalid input. Please enter a valid price with a decimal point.")
                
    macdsignal(macd, data)
    print("regreso de entrada", len(data))

    data.loc[len(data)] = [timestamp, price, macd]

    print("lendata =", len(data))
    # para imprimir solo la última fila:
    # print(data.iloc[-1].to_frame().T)
    last_100_rows = data.tail(100)
    print("conformó impresión últimas 100 filas")
    print(last_100_rows.to_string(index=False))

    # Espera 5 segundos antes de tomar otra captura de pantalla
    time.sleep(5)
```

Este código corre bien, hasta cuando introduzco la instrucción para calcular la EMA 12, se tranca y no da error, sale esto:

```
lendata = 15
conformó impresión últimas 100 filas
          Timestamp   price  macd
2024-01-24 20:48:49 39977.9   0.0
2024-01-24 20:48:55 39988.7   0.0
2024-01-24 20:49:00 39990.0   0.0
2024-01-24 20:49:05 39981.2   0.0
2024-01-24 20:49:10 39971.2   0.0
2024-01-24 20:49:15 39971.2   0.0
2024-01-24 20:49:21 39974.8   0.0
2024-01-24 20:49:26 39974.8   0.0
2024-01-24 20:49:31 39974.8   0.0
2024-01-24 20:49:36 39974.8   0.0
2024-01-24 20:49:41 39980.0   0.0
2024-01-24 20:49:47 39976.2   0.0
2024-01-24 20:49:52 39976.2   0.0
2024-01-24 20:49:57 39979.4   0.0
2024-01-24 20:50:02 39960.8   0.0
2024-01-24 20:50:08
captura realizada
El número extraído de la imagen es: 39964.1
len(data) previous =  15 39960.8
percent difference =  0.008258092931061526
39964.1
short ema =  0     39977.900000
1     39979.561538
2     39981.167456
3     39981.172462
4     39979.638237
5     39978.340047
6     39977.795424
7     39977.334590
8     39976.944653
9     39976.614706
10    39977.135521
11    39976.991595
12    39976.869811
13    39977.259071
14    39974.726906
Name: price, dtype: float64
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\VICTOR\Documentos\CODIGOS\capturaprecio dtaframe MACD 240124.py", line 112, in <module>
    macdsignal(macd, data)
  File "d:\VICTOR\Documentos\CODIGOS\capturaprecio dtaframe MACD 240124.py", line 32, in macdsignal
    data.loc[len(data) -1, "macd"] = macd
    ~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\VICTOR\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 885, in __setitem__
\core\indexing.py", line 1893, in _setitem_with_indexer
    self._setitem_with_indexer_split_path(indexer, value, name)
  File "C:\Users\VICTOR\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1914, in _setitem_with_indexer_split_path
    value = self._align_series(indexer, Series(value))
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\VICTOR\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 2368, in _align_series
    raise ValueError("Incompatible indexer with Series")
ValueError: Incompatible indexer with Series
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe un resumen del problema ya en el título de la pregunta. Podrías poner por ejemplo el mensaje de error que tienes. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

El problema se debe a que estas intentando asignar una serie como valor de una celda de la columna *macd*:

- `data["price"].ewm(span=12, adjust=False).mean()` genera una Serie ya que aplica mean sobre una "ventana móvil":

  ```
  0     39977.900000
  1     39979.561538
  2     39981.167456
  3     39981.172462
  4     39979.638237
  5     39978.340047
  6     39977.795424
  7     39977.334590
  8     39976.944653
  9     39976.614706
  10    39977.135521
  11    39976.991595
  12    39976.869811
  13    39977.259071
  14    39974.726906
  Name: price, dtype: float64
  ```
- `data.loc[len(data) -1, "macd"]` por su parte selecciona la ultima celda/valor de la columna *macd*

Esto hace que con:

```
data.loc[len(data) -1, "macd"] = macd
```

intentes asignar una serie a la ultima celda de la columna *macd*, esperaría un float como valor pero le estas intentando asignar una serie de floats y es ahí donde salta la excepción.

Por tanto, o bien asignas la serie a la columna al completo:

```
data["macd"] = macd
```

> ```
>               Timestamp    price          macd
> 0   2024-01-24 20:48:49  39977.9  39977.900000
> 1   2024-01-24 20:48:55  39988.7  39979.561538
> 2   2024-01-24 20:49:00  39990.0  39981.167456
> 3   2024-01-24 20:49:05  39981.2  39981.172462
> 4   2024-01-24 20:49:10  39971.2  39979.638237
> 5   2024-01-24 20:49:15  39971.2  39978.340047
> 6   2024-01-24 20:49:21  39974.8  39977.795424
> 7   2024-01-24 20:49:26  39974.8  39977.334590
> 8   2024-01-24 20:49:31  39974.8  39976.944653
> 9   2024-01-24 20:49:36  39974.8  39976.614706
> 10  2024-01-24 20:49:41  39980.0  39977.135521
> 11  2024-01-24 20:49:47  39976.2  39976.991595
> 12  2024-01-24 20:49:52  39976.2  39976.869811
> 13  2024-01-24 20:49:57  39979.4  39977.259071
> 14  2024-01-24 20:50:02  39960.8  39974.726906
> ```

o le asignas un solo valor (float) a la ultima celda, por ejemplo:

```
data.loc[data.index[-1], "macd"] = macd[macd.index[-1]]
```

> ```
>               Timestamp    price          macd
> 0   2024-01-24 20:48:49  39977.9      0.000000
> 1   2024-01-24 20:48:55  39988.7      0.000000
> 2   2024-01-24 20:49:00  39990.0      0.000000
> 3   2024-01-24 20:49:05  39981.2      0.000000
> 4   2024-01-24 20:49:10  39971.2      0.000000
> 5   2024-01-24 20:49:15  39971.2      0.000000
> 6   2024-01-24 20:49:21  39974.8      0.000000
> 7   2024-01-24 20:49:26  39974.8      0.000000
> 8   2024-01-24 20:49:31  39974.8      0.000000
> 9   2024-01-24 20:49:36  39974.8      0.000000
> 10  2024-01-24 20:49:41  39980.0      0.000000
> 11  2024-01-24 20:49:47  39976.2      0.000000
> 12  2024-01-24 20:49:52  39976.2      0.000000
> 13  2024-01-24 20:49:57  39979.4      0.000000
> 14  2024-01-24 20:50:02  39960.8  39974.726906
> ```